# How to print the maximum number of a stream of inputs, before reaching the first 0? [Python]

Tags: python, max, zero

As the title says, given a stream of numbers, the program has to print the maximum number before reaching the first 0.

### The code I managed to write is this:

```
l = []

while True:
    a=int(input())
    if a==0:
        print(max(l))
        break
    else:
        l.append(a)
```

But as you can see, I actually print the max number in the list after the input reaches the 0.

I have no clue as to how to actually print the max number before reaching the first 0.
Any ideas are most appreciated!

Edit:
Screenshot from the source. Profound Academy

[Screenshot from problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrjL.png)

[Site problem.](https://profound.academy/python-introduction/OSJP2kdfRNgawJv2rKLy)

Comment: That's impossible. Probably you're misinterpreting what you're asked to do.

Comment: Can you elaborate/confirm how the program supposed to get the *input*s?  Eg. asking the user continuously until hitting *0*?  Like one number per line ... or?

Comment: How is it physically possible to know that you're supposed to print the max, if the 0 hasn't arrived yet? The next number could be a 0, but it could also be something else.

Comment: The *numbers* are before the 0, not the `print`. Your answer should work. Don't overthink it.

Comment: "Given a stream of numbers, the program has to print the maximum number before reaching the first 0."

This is the only text given regarding the problem. There is an Input and Output window as to show what happens if there is a certain input and what should I get on the output.

The thing is, the way I solved it, it should work (it does on the public tests I can use to test the code), but when I upload the problem and it is being assessed on the "Private tests" it returns that I have failed and not passed them.

Comment: Where is this from? And can you show a screenshot of that "Input and Output window"?

Comment: You get a **runtime error**, don't you? Really should've said that.

Comment: Yes, it's a runtime error as you say. I'm just new at this and I'm just getting the grasp of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it at the site. You get a **runtime error**. And the reason is that they have an input where the first number is 0, so you try `max` on an empty list. In that case you're apparently supposed to print 0. It gets accepted if you change `max(l)` to `max(l, default=0))`.

Verdict: The task description or its input is buggy. I suggest you tell them and they should fix it.

Comment: That makes sense though, if the first input is a zero and I'm printing an empty list...didn't think about that. The issue is solved and I'll write them about it asap. Thank you!